# Nuxt dynamic routes based on Firebase data

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

I'm having a Nuxt app in **SPA mode** hosted on **Netlify**.
I'm authenticating and storing users data with **Firebase**.

I want to display all users profile on a dynamic routes.
For example

```
https://www.myapp.com/users/martcube
```

(where "martcube" is the documentid)

Is this even posible with the given stack of technologies ?
If you need extra code or info, write me and i will edit my question right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly, you want to:

1. have a dynamic route for each `documentid` (`.../users/martcube`)
2. parse the `documentid` information from your route and fetch data from your Firebase database

---

### 1) dynamic routes

- create the `pages` folder structure for the `users` pages like this:
  `pages > users > _id > index.vue`

This will allow for dynamic routes:

- `.../users/test`
- `.../users/test2`

If you want a page for the `.../users` route when no `documentid` is attached to the route simply create an `index.vue` inside the `users` folder.

### 2) parse the information from the route and fetch the firebase database

- use the [fetch method](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) inside your page (`pages > users > _id > index.vue`):

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  async fetch ({ store, params }) {
    // get documentid parameter
    var documentid = params.id;
    
    // get data from the firebase database
    await store.dispatch('getFirebaseData', { documentid: documentid})
  }
}
</script>
```